# Bin Packing variant

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraint-satisfaction

I am currently struggling with a bin packing variant, where we have fuel and compartments of a tank truck. Some industry constraints apply, but the whole picture is that you must fit the total volume with the optimum way through the compartments.
I have created a model, which works almost perfectly, where I try to minimize the wastage (from all the compartments, not only the used).
Now let's say that I have a preference in using as front compartments as possible, namely if the 2nd compartment and the 8th compartment have 1000lt capacity, then I want to use the 2nd compartment. I want this to happen only when the wastage of the one solution is equal to the other.

Hence, If I have a solution with wastage 1100 lt and the 2nd compartment is empty, but I have another solution with wastage 1100lt and the 8th compartment is empty, I want the model to extract the second.

Is there a way to model preference constraints, without diverging from the original objective (minimizing wastage)?

**EDIT**
Let me explain a little more about my objective. Right now the objective is

$\sum_i{\sum_j{c_{j}-y_{ij}}}$

Where $c_{j}$ is the capacity of each compartment j and $y_{ij}$ is the assigned quantity of element $i$ in compartment $j$. If we assume that the new part of the objective function is to be found (I'm counting on you), then I can replace the function above with:

$M*\sum_i{\sum_j{c_{j}-y_{ij}}}+μ*F$

Where M is going to be a big number and μ  a small number. F would be the second objective.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to solve the system without this preference constraint and find the wastage.  Suppose you can achieve wastage 1100.  Then, add a new constraint that the wastage cannot exceed 1100, and modify the objective function to slightly penalize use of the back components, and solve that modified problem.